# How to activate authentication in Apache Airflow

Tags: authentication, webserver, airflow

Airflow version- 1.9.0

I have installed apache airflow and post configuration i am able to run sample DAG's with sequential executor.

Also, created new sample user which i can see under Admin > Users.

But unable to get the login window/screen when we visit webserver adress at :8080/ it directly opens up Airflow webserver with admin user. 
It will be great help if anyone can provide some info on how to activate login screen/page, so that user credentials can be used for logging into webserver.

Steps followed to enable **web user authentication**:
https://airflow.apache.org/security.html?highlight=authentication

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Check the following in your `airflow.cfg` file:

```
[webserver]
authenticate = True
auth_backend = airflow.contrib.auth.backends.password_auth
```

And also remember to **Restart Airflow Webserver**, if it still doesn't work, run `airflow initdb` and restart the webserver.

Also, double-check in `airflow.cfg` file that it does not contain multiple configurations for `authenticate` or `auth_backend`. If there is more than one occurrence, than it can cause that issue.

If necessary, install flask_bcrpyt package of python2.x/3.x
For instance,
$ python3.7 -m pip install flask_bcrypt

Make sure you have an admin user created,

```
airflow create_user -r Admin -u admin -e admin@acme.com -f admin -l user -p *****
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestions @kaxil. I tried again both of them as before, but no success. It still directly log into webserver UI as admin.

Comment: Can you double check in `airflow.cfg` file that it does not contain multiple configuration for `authenticate` or `auth_backend`. If there are more than one occurence, than it can cause that issue

Comment: Can you copy/paste your `airflow.cfg` file here?

Comment: you were right, there was duplicate entry for authenticate in airflow.cfg file. Thanks for pointing it. Now i can see login window. Any idea what is default password for admin user which is super user in this case. How can i login using admin.

Comment: There is no user created at this point. You will have to create a user by following the steps at https://airflow.apache.org/security.html?highlight=authentication#password

Comment: Also, please accept the answer as it solved your problem. Thanks :)

Answer (score 7):

1. edit `airflow.cfg` 
   inside `[webserver]` section

   - change `authenticate = True`.  by default it is set to False.
   - add `auth_backend = airflow.contrib.auth.backends.password_auth`.
   - change `rbac = True` for Role-based-access-control – RBAC.
2. `airflow initdb`
3. restart **airflow webserver**

Comment: Hi @Ganesh, seems like I do exactly as you say, I'm using Airflow version 1.10.10. The case is that I get "Airflow 404 = lots of circles". Any idea why?

Comment: That means airflow Webserver is not running. Try restarting it. 
You are hitting http://{ip}:8080/home URL right ?

Comment: Hi @Ganesh, you helped me, the problem was the actual URL. I was using /admin instead of /home (!). I really thank you.

Comment: @RafaIK I had the same issue. adding /login to the url works too

Answer (score 2):

just add `rbac = True` to `airflow.cfg`, and you are good to go.
Now all you need to is restart your airflow webserver.
And in case if you want to add a new user. You can use this command,

```
 airflow create_user -r Admin -u admin -f Ashish -l malgawa -p test123 -e ashishmalgawa@gmail.com
```

> “-r” is the role we want for the user
> “-u” is the username
> “-f” is the first name
> “-l” is the last name
> “-e” is the email id
> “-p” is the password

For more details, you can follow this article
[https://www.cloudwalker.io/2020/03/01/airflow-rbac-role-based-access-control/#:~:text=RBAC%20is%20the%20quickest%20way,access%20to%20DAGs%20as%20well](https://www.cloudwalker.io/2020/03/01/airflow-rbac-role-based-access-control/#:%7E:text=RBAC%20is%20the%20quickest%20way,access%20to%20DAGs%20as%20well)