# Enabling airflow auth causes problems connecting to host

Tags: python-3.x, airflow

I freshly installed apache-airflow on a machine running ubuntu. I have run

```
airflow initdb
airflow webserver
airflow scheduler
```

without running into issues. Now i would like to turn on password authentication for users of the webapp. So i edited the airflow.cfg file to reflect this

```
[webserver]
authenticate = True
auth_backend = airflow.contrib.auth.backends.password_auth
rbac = True
```

and then created an admin user from the command line

```
airflow create_user -r Admin ***credentials***
```

however now when I navigate to the correct url (public IP:8080) I get a message from the server saying

```
**Airflow 404 = lots of circles**
```

I seem to have run into the same issue as a commenter on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52056809/how-to-activate-authentication-in-apache-airflow?rq=1) thread. I know i have the correct URL because i was able to access the airflow UI just fine before changing the auth configuration. I *expect* to be taken to a login screen, but get the "circles" instead.

Answer (score 2):

adding /login or /home to the url fixes the issue.